# Ps4 free monthly games

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I have a question. I am subscribed to PS+, and I started downloading a free game in June. Can I download it anytime I want or is there a deadline before they charge me for it?

Answer (score 2):

Once you added the PS+ game to your library, you can download and play it any time, as long as you still have PS+.

If you stop having PS+, you can no longer play/download the game AFAIK.